# Running MAMP and WAMP on the same thumbdrive?

Tags: wamp, local, mamp

Recently started working in a tech-agnostic shop, and I find myself switching between OSX and Windows machines with some frequency. I've got a great set of HTML tools I use in my local MAMP, and recently figured out how to set up a standalone MAMP on a thumb drive for switching Mac-to-Mac. The downfall is I can't take them with me onto a Windows box.

What I want to do is have MAMP and WAMP on the thumb drive, running off the same database and webroot (never concurrently, obviously). Research has proved fruitless, the most help I've found is importing a MAMP environment into WAMP. Is it possible/practical to run MAMP and WAMP off the same database/webroot?

Comment: For the record, the standalone MAMP solution I found was to alias /Applications/MAMP/ to my thumbdrive. Obviously this isn't a complete solution, since it will still reference the local machine's MySQL - my tools didn't require a database, so it was a good patch solution for a while.